# iTunes Connect iFrame

Tags: iframe, app-store-connect, x-frame-options

I would like to embed the iTunes connect portal into an iFrame for a customer web app I am building.

Q1. Has anyone achieved this, if so how?
Q2. When I have tried I get an:

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Any help would be great, I am trying to make it easier for my customer to get access to setup in app purchases.

Comment: Wait. Why do you want to iframe "iTunes Connect" ? Weird.

Comment: It is because the client has to add content to both my platform and iTunes Connect, and I want to try and make the process simpler by giving a crib sheet of information for the iTunes Connect in app purchase setup process, thanks